# Binary Search Tree Algorithm - Start Searching From a Node Other Than Root

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, binary

Is there a way to search in a binary search tree starting from a node other than the root? E.g to start searching from a node in the third level of the tree.

Comment: Do you maintain pointers to anything other than the head of the tree?

Comment: Yes you can start searching from anywhere, but if you dont start from the root there is not guarantee you will find the value you are looking for

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, there are no pointers other than the head.

Comment: Mitchel0022, how to get to the node to start searching form there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to search in a binary search tree starting from a node
>   other than the root?

Yes. There is. 
But not with the traditional `Binary Search Tree` data structure.
You will have to modify the structure of a `Node` to achieve that.

One most straight forward way to achieve that is to have a pointer to root node from any other node. That way, you will be able to go to your root node directly from any given node and apply regular `Binary Search` algorithm. This method includes overhead of saving one more pointer to `Root` and would not change the time complexity of `Binary Serach`, it would remain `O(lgN)`

Other a bit complex way to achieve that would be to have a pointer to immidiate parent from any node. Given any node, you can first perform binary search on that subtree to find if the node to find exists on the subtree of the given node. That will finish the algorithm in `O(lgM)` where `M` is the number of nodes in the subtree. That search would be bit efficient because `M < N`. If you do not find the node in the subtree, then you will have to traverse back to the root. ( `Root` will have `null` as the parent pointer ) While traversing back, you can also track whether the node you are currently at is the node to find, if is is, you can directly return from there. Once you reach the root of the tree, you can apply standard `Binary Serach` algorithm. The time complexity for this method remains same as `O(lgN)`. In most cases, the algorithm would finish faster than standard `Binary Search`.